# Заполнить матрицу змейкой

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста исправить код !

Должно получиться вот так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```cs
int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] a = new int[k, m];
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = c++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(a[j,i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: А получается как?

Comment: В чем сложности то?

Comment: Эта задача еще проще, чем ваша [прошлая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1202845/373567). Совсем никаких идей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл по столбцам (слева направо), внутри него цикл по строкам, направление которого чередуется (сначала сверху вниз, затем снизу вверх). Получаем примерно такой код:

```
var rowsCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var columnsCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var a = new int[rowsCount, columnsCount];
var number = 1;
var positiveDirection = true;
for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
{
    if (positiveDirection)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            a[i, j] = number++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = rowsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            a[i, j] = number++;
        }
    }

    positiveDirection = !positiveDirection;
}

for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columnsCount; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(a[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Какие числа ты вводил в консоль ? У меня при любом числе out of range (

Comment: @Aligat опечатка же, вот здесь `for (int i = rowsCount - 1; i >= 0; j--)`, должно быть `i--`

Comment: @aepot спасибо, не заметил

Answer (score 2):

А давайте лучше по месту вычислять, кто там сидит. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1KDiWw)

И делайте имена переменных такие, чтобы не путаться, что в них лежит.

```
   int hgt = 4;
   int wdt = 5;
   int[,] a = new int[hgt, wdt];

    for (int y = 0; y < hgt; y++)
      for (int x = 0; x < wdt; x++) 
        a[y, x] = ((x%2)==0?y:(hgt-y-1)) + 1 + x * hgt;

    for (int y = 0; y < hgt; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < wdt; x++) 
           Console.Write(a[y,x] + " ");
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Тогда уж `width` и `height`, а в качестве индексов всегда `i` и `j` понятнее были, чем `y` и `x` на их местах.